squidからのリクエストヘッダーにX-Forwarded-Forを追加することができない
VMware上のCentOSにsquid（Version 3.5.20）をインストールしています。
クライアントPCにプロキシ設定をしてブラウザからsquid経由でウェブサーバーにアクセスできることまでは確認しています。
リクエストヘッダにX-Forwarded-Forを追加したいためsquid.confにforwarded_for on等の設定を追加しましたがリクエストヘッダにはなにも表示されません。
他に何か設定すべき個所や不備などありましたら教えてください。
#
# Recommended minimum configuration:
#

# Example rule allowing access from your local networks.
# Adapt to list your (internal) IP networks from where browsing
# should be allowed
acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8     # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src 172.16.0.0/12  # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src 192.168.0.0/16 # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src fc00::/7       # RFC 4193 local private network range
acl localnet src fe80::/10      # RFC 4291 link-local (directly plugged) machines

acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80          # http
acl Safe_ports port 21          # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443         # https
acl Safe_ports port 70          # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210         # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280         # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488         # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591         # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777         # multiling http
acl CONNECT method CONNECT

#
# Recommended minimum Access Permission configuration:
#
# Deny requests to certain unsafe ports
http_access deny !Safe_ports

# Deny CONNECT to other than secure SSL ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports

# Only allow cachemgr access from localhost
http_access allow localhost manager
http_access deny manager

# We strongly recommend the following be uncommented to protect innocent
# web applications running on the proxy server who think the only
# one who can access services on "localhost" is a local user
#http_access deny to_localhost

#
# INSERT YOUR OWN RULE(S) HERE TO ALLOW ACCESS FROM YOUR CLIENTS
#

# Example rule allowing access from your local networks.
# Adapt localnet in the ACL section to list your (internal) IP networks
# from where browsing should be allowed
http_access allow localnet
http_access allow localhost

# And finally deny all other access to this proxy
http_access deny all

# Squid normally listens to port 3128
http_port 3128

# Uncomment and adjust the following to add a disk cache directory.
#cache_dir ufs /var/spool/squid 100 16 256

# Leave coredumps in the first cache dir
coredump_dir /var/spool/squid

#
# Add any of your own refresh_pattern entries above these.
#
refresh_pattern ^ftp:           1440    20%     10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:        1440    0%      1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0     0%      0
refresh_pattern .               0       20%     4320

# ---以下を設定を追加---
via on
forwarded_for on
request_header_access Via allow all
request_header_access  X-Forwarded-For allow all
request_header_access Referer allow all
reply_header_access Via allow all
reply_header_access X-Forwarded-For allow all
follow_x_forwarded_for allow localnet

logformat combined %>a %ui [%tl] "%rm %ru HTTP/%rv" >Hs %st \ "%{Referer}>h" "%{X-Forwarded-For}>h" %Ss:%Sh
access_log /var/log/squid/access.log combined
# --------

ログの確認
192.168.10.113 - [08/Apr/2024:22:18:52 +0900] "CONNECT taruo.net:443 HTTP/1.1" >Hs 6836 \ "-" "-" TCP_TUNNEL:HIER_DIRECT


ご自分で解決したのであれば、あなたが理解した内容を回答に記入してください。(参考:自分の質問に回答できますか？)

ご指摘ありがとうございます。回答に記入しました。

ログは CONNECT メソッドなので、SSL(HTTPS)通信ですね。
SSL(HTTPS)通信の場合、ブラウザ - Webサーバー間で暗号化通信を確立しますので、Squid は中身を見ることも(ヘッダ追加など)変更することもできません。

リクエストヘッダについてはEdgeのDevToolのネットワークログから確認をしていたためsquidでヘッダが追加される前の誤った情報を見ていました。
下記、ウェブサイトにてHTTP通信による確認をしたところ、
既存の設定でX-Forwaded-Forの情報が表示できていました。
URL：http://taruo.net/e/

HTTPS通信の場合はSquidにてヘッダの追加、変更ができないということでこちらは想定通りの動作だと理解いたしました。
